# TimeSpan string format exception

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, string-formatting, timespan

I've developed a web program in visual studio 2008 and converted it to 2010. In a `Datagrid` I have a data column with `TimeSpan` value. In 2008 I gave it string format `0:hh:mm` and after the conversion I was getting a `FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format`. I corrected the string formattig to `0:hh\:mm` as I found in Microsoft documentation for .NET 4.0. When I run the application from visual studio it works but when I copy it and run from the IIS it's still giving that error. What could be the problem?

Comment: You corrected from `0:hh:mm` to `0:hh:mm`?

Comment: what application pool does your IIS use?

Comment: @Tim Schmelter I corrected that to 0:hh\:mm.

Comment: @aiapatag I don't know. How do I find out?

Comment: http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/applicationpools

Comment: @aiapatag The application pool is ASP.NET v4.0.

Comment: Having the same problem and it is noticeable when debugging with the web app running under iis works in immediate window but throws error when stepping through the code.

Answer (score 4):

In .NET version 3.5 and earlier, the `TimeSpan` struct wasn't `IFormattable`. Using a format string as in `string.Format("Ipsum {0:HERE} ipsum", yourTimeSpan)` would just ignore the format.

Since .NET 4.0, the `TimeSpan` is `IFormattable`. There's a [new overload of `ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd784379.aspx) because of that, and it is called instead.

Comment: I'm not using tostring there I'm using the DataFormatString property of the gridview collumn. Also in my edit of the question I wrote that I changed to 0:hh\:mm as documented in your link.

Comment: @DovMiller Can we see the _exact_ code statement where you use the format string? Is the backspace ``\`` properly escaped? When you run directly from Visual Studio, what version of .NET do you use? What version of .NET do you use when running through the IIS? It is possible to turn off the new `IFormattable` character of time spans, see [`<TimeSpan_LegacyFormatMode>` Element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee803802.aspx).

Comment: The markup of the grid collumn is DataFormatString="{0:hh\:mm}". In Visual Studio 4.0 and in IIS the application pool is ASP.NET v4.0.

Comment: I can't see why it would work in one situation and not in another, both under .NET 4.0. If it is somehow the backslash ``\`` which cause you truoble, remember that you can also "protect" the colon by putting it inside `' ... '`, that would be `DataFormatString="{0:hh':'mm}"`.